# String disappears when I use String.Substring

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET to create the website. But on my way, I was told to use `string.Substring(int, int)` to create a substring when the length increases.

I also searched for a better option here about the character limit in ASP.NET but either they were for ASP.NET Web Forms or they were for C#, but I am using ASP.NET Web Pages.

The code that I am using is this:

```
@if(message.Length > 80) {
   message.Substring(0, 80);
} else {
   <text>@message</text>
}
```

The issue is that, when the character count is under 80 the message is shown to the user, but when it exceeds the limit (above 80) the message is not viewed. However, I have tried to show 3 messages at a time one with a length 10 other with 25 and the last one with 117, the last one was not shown. As it had to pass the first block. The other who passed from `else` block. They got written down.

I think there is some kind of bug in the block, but I am not able to figure it out. I also want a better suggestion to break the string, where the character limit catches up. I want to break the string where the character limit `80` comes up. Any good idea of how to do this? If the `substring` is the best then please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In else part you have written

```
<text>@message</text>
```

But this is missing in if block.

Please add this to if block

```
 if(message.Length > 80) {
      message= message.Substring(0, 80);
     <text>@message</text>
    }
     else {
       <text>@message</text>
    }
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Helpfull! I was missing this block. Thanks :)

Comment: if my answer help you then please mark my answer to accepted. So other can be benefited by it.

Comment: It would be better if he double checked the problem instead of posting here! +1 for answering

Comment: I do agree with you that he should checked the code before posting. But some time we cant find out our own silly mistakes.

Comment: True, subin! I should have checked it! :D But, I was being so much silly for checking the code format, that I missed the `<text>` block.